# PyQT "grading bars" in cell

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5

Is there any way of creating grading bars in qt table cells:

For example, if cell `item.text() == "0%"` then keep background of the cell empty. If it is 100% then fill it *completely* with green background. If it is 50% then fill half of the cell background and set it to some colour e.g. between red and green.

Is there any way of doing this in the qt platform? Apparently I'll need delegates but I've not used them before.

**SOLVED** by mrjj from qt forums https://forum.qt.io/topic/60971/setpalette-for-qtablewidgetitem-in-qt5

Comment: Why did I get downvote, was anything wrong with my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but its probably because you've included minimal code and haven't demonstrate how you've attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr oh I see, that sounds fair. I thought it was more of a "is this possible" question. Because of having to fill up a % of the cell background instead of the whole thing

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Am i allowed to repost the question with qt5 tag?

Comment: I just added the tag for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since a [QTableWidgetItem](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#row) is an object in its own right, you should be able to just [set the palette like so](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Windows%20with%20gradient%20backgrounds):

```
 p = QPalette()
 gradient = QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400)
 gradient.setColorAt(0.0, QColor(240, 240, 240))
 gradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor(240, 160, 160))
 p.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(gradient))
 item.setPalette(p) # Assuming item is your table cell
```

Comment: I'm not sure this does exactly what he asks, since this makes a gradient across the entire cell, but it sounds like @Lobstw wanted a bar that's, say, 50% of the cell. Though you can do that here by properly spacing the gradient.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this answer sooner. I've been trying to port the code over to pyqt5 and everything apart from the last line is fine, can't seem to be able to implement `.setPalette`. Also @Dval, could you maybe show me what you mean by spacing the gradient? Thank you both.

Comment: Loosely, 
     gradient.setColorAt(0.0, QColor(240, 240, 240))

     gradient.setColorAt(x, QColor(240, 240, 240))

     gradient.setColorAt(x+.01, QColor(240, 0, 0))
     gradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor(240, 0, 0))
will force the gradient to be white for the first x percent. As for the .setPalette, I don't know. Lego's code works in PyQt4 and I'm not familiar with changes in 5.

Comment: @Dval Thank you for the explanation however after reading the documentation I think `QTableWidgetItem` no longer has a `setPalette` option in Qt5, which is a bit of a nuisance!